# Update attempt in .NET Core throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing an application where I do not necessarily need to use .NET core identity for login. However, whenever I try updating a record, it throws the following exception

> The instance of entity type 'StApplications' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ApplicationId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)

**`StApplications`** is the table where I want to update record

**Below is the code in my `ApplicationRepository`**

```
public async  Task<StApplications> UpdateAsync(StApplications obj)
{
    var updatedApplication = _context.Update(obj);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return updatedApplication.Entity;
}
```

**Followed by the code in my `ApplicationController`, the POST method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Biodata(StApplications stApplications)
{
    var application = await _ApplicationRepository.GetByIdAsync(stApplications.ApplicationId) ;
    
    if (application == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var updatedapplication = await _ApplicationRepository.UpdateAsync(stApplications);
    return RedirectToAction("Olevel", new { id = updatedapplication.ApplicationId});
}
```

Comment: Error message is clear, where's the issue? Obviously, somewherre in your code, you are retrieving the object, then trying to update a **new** instance (with the same key). You have either to use the existing instance or detach the previous instance, or use EF's `Attach` methods

Comment: I think there are errors within the POST method. _stApplications_ is not in your context. _application_ would be but the code does nothing with it. It also seems that you misunderstood _ModelState_ because it seems of little use when a DB entry could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

You must first set `Detached` object in local entities
and then set the `Modified` state on the new object.

```
    public virtual async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool saveNow = true)
    {
        Assert.NotNull(entity, nameof(entity));
        AttachEntity(entity);
        Entities.Update(entity);
        if (saveNow)
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    private void AttachEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        var local = Entities.Local.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == entity.Id);
        if (local != null)
        {
            DbContext.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        Entities.Attach(entity);
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be saving `stApplications`, but rather, mapping the values from that onto the `application` instance you pulled from the database, and then saving `application`.